# how to add new icon image for newly created Dev express barButtonItem..?

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress, windows, ribbon-control

I am currently working C# windows application can any one tell me how to add new icon for the 
newly created barButtonItem  tell me how to add new image for that button.

If i select large image Index property then it shows only the old icons that are available Can any one tell me how to add new image for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on how you are using your `barButtonItem`

we use it with our own set of images. you can access those via

`global::Resources.(yourOwnPath);`

as stated here http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarItem_Glyphtopic

you can also use a list of images and use the index field or set the large Glyph of Glyph property of the button